# Cross-match a number of worksheets to one master worksheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

Hopefully the title is not too confusing. Basically, I have a master list of addresses and those addresses are listed in multiple columns (Column A - street number, Column B - street name, Column C - street type etc) and I get a another set of addresses on a daily basis with the same address formatting. What I need to do is cross-match the daily changing list of addresses to the first list to remove any matching entries.

So, for example, if the first list has 123 Main St on it, I have to ensure that there are no entries of 123 Main St on any subsequent daily lists. I'm using one address as an example but the lists contain upwards of 10000 addresses that have to be cross matched. 
I don't need them flagged or highlighted, just deleted from the daily lists (though if they have to be flagged or highlighted, I could work with that)

Any help here would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If your master list is in `Sheet1` (Columns `A`-`C`, let’s say rows 1-99)
and your daily list is in Columns `A`-`C` of another sheet,
put this into cell `D1` of the new sheet:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A$1:A$99, A1, Sheet1!B$1:B$99, B1, Sheet1!C$1:C$99, C1)
```

and drag/fill down. 
This will evaluate to 1 in rows that match a row in `Sheet1` and 0 for rows that don’t.

This works fine for rows where all three cells are non-blank (e.g., `A42` = `123`, `B42` = `Main`, and `C42` = `St`), but not so well when there are blanks (e.g., `A42` = `10`, `B42` = `Broadway`, and `C42` = *(blank)*). 
One way to fix this is to type an apostrophe (`'`) into each blank cell in `Sheet2`. 
Another is to put a zero in every blank cell on `Sheet1`
(you can use formatting to make it invisible).